# SASS ‘null’ value is being output to compiled CSS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

Using ‘null’ should prune the associated property – as outlined here http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2012/08/23/sass-3-2-is-released/ – instead they appear in compiled CSS.

For example:

```
div {
  background-color: null;
  color: red;
}
```

*should* output to:

```
div {
  color: red;
}
```

but instead outputs to the former example, which obviously adds invalid CSS.

I’m using:

- GruntJS (grunt-contrib-sass as the task)
- SASS 3.3.0
- Compass 1.0.0.alpha.17
- Susy 1.0.9

Comment: Not to mention an invalid value

Comment: In what instance would you be explicitly using null like that?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is right in the page you linked. I don't use SASS, but it looks like null is a data type. You have to pass a variable that contains null. SASS will interpret the variable `$color` as null and then remove it. Otherwise, it seems that it interprets `null` as just a string and passes it through accordingly.

```
$color: null;
div {
  width: 23px;
  color: $color;
  border: 2px solid $color;
}
```

becomes

```
div {
  width: 23px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```